# Sails app on Heroku not connecting to JawsDB

Tags: mysql, heroku, sails.js

I have deployed a Sails api to Heroku I had been using the `localdiskdb` for quite a while without any issues. I have recently spun up a JawsDB instance to connect with the api.

```
jawsDB:{
  adapter: 'sails-mysql',
  url: process.env.JAWSDB_URL,
  schema: true
},
```

I have set the model in production.js to jawsDB.

- We have been using a local mysql instance with no issues in development
- I also have tested it on a Amazon RDS instance that I connected to locally
- I have tried all the connection strings that JawsDB provides
- I have tested different arguments in the sails adapter, including ssl: true
- I have swapped out jawsDB for localdiskdb in the production.js file to test if it was even hitting it and it worked with no issues
- I have Papertrail set up and get no errors or any strange log entries of any kind when lifting sails

I have been at this for the better part of a few days. At this point I really think I am missing something rather dumb. If anyone has any experience with setting this up the help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I am dumb! I didn't have enough error logging to notice my application quickly used more than the 10 available connections that JawsDB offers for their free account.

My solution, use Amazon RDS.